# Add tag synonym for [tag:wsl]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

As the [global maximum tag length has been increased to 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/230282), now the tag [wsl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wsl) should be renamed to [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux) (or similar) and act as a synonym to the latter.

Other SE sites have already done the change

- [Should WSL be a synonym for Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12738/241386)
- [The tag 'windows-subsystem-for-linux' is too long; the maximum length is 25 characters](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4226/44425)
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-subsystem-for-linux/synonyms

The same thing should also be done on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been done. All questions previously tagged with [wsl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wsl) are now tagged with [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux) and [wsl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wsl) is now a synonym pointing to [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux).